# programmatically adding product to cart returns every time diffrent quote id in android application

Tags: magento-1.9, programmatically, sales-quote, multiple-add-to-cart

> Below code work perfect on IOS application but now work in android application.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("../app/Mage.php");
umask(0); 
Mage::app();

$store_id=$_POST["store_id"];
$valusof=$_POST["cartproduct"]; //$valusof=array(array("product_id"=>"32","quantity"=>"1","option_id"=>'4'),array("product_id"=>"12","quantity"=>"5"));
$result_array = array();

if(isset($store_id) || is_numeric($store_id)){
    $store=$store_id;
}
else
{
    $store="1";
}
if(!is_array($valusof) or empty($valusof) ){
    $result_array["message"]="Product quantity or Product Id or Option id is null add Quantity Or Not in Array Formate";
    $result_array["status"]="0";
    echo json_encode($result_array);
}
else
{
    foreach ($valusof as $value) {
        Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                         ->load($value["product_id"]);

        $cart->addProduct($value["product_id"], array( 
                'qty' => $value["quantity"], 
                'super_attribute' => array( 92 => $value["option_id"] )
                )
            );
    }

    $cart->save();

    $cart1=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $cart1->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    $result_array["quoteid"]=$quoteid=$cart1->getQuoteId();
    $result_array["items_count"]=Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
    //get quote using sales/quote
    $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteid);
    $quote->setStoreId($store);
    $quote->save();

    $store_id=$quote->getStoreId();
    if(isset($store_id) || is_numeric($store_id)){
        $current_currency_code=Mage::app()->getStore($store_id)->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $currency_code=$current_currency_code;
    }else{
        $currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
    }
    $base_currency_code=Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();


    $base_grand_total=$quote->getBaseGrandTotal();
    $grand_total=Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($base_grand_total, $base_currency_code , $currency_code);
    $base_subtotal=$quote->getBaseSubtotal();
    $subtotal=Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($base_subtotal, $base_currency_code , $currency_code);
    $base_subtotal_with_discount=$quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount();
    $subtotal_with_discount=Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($base_subtotal_with_discount, $base_currency_code , $currency_code);


    $quote->setGrandTotal($grand_total)->setSubtotal($subtotal)->setSubtotalWithDiscount($subtotal_with_discount);
    $quote->save();

    $result_array["message"]="Product added to cart.";
    $result_array["status"]="1";
    echo json_encode($result_array);
}
?>
```

Comment: pasting a php file and waiting for someone to debug it is not the way to go  so don't expect any help here.

Comment: I am just asking there is no issue at all worked on IOS application perfect.. i just want to know there is any session issue ?